# 'mail' not working in Script same way it is working from command line

Tags: unix, shell

The below line of code/command is working as expected if I run it from Unix terminal, but not if I include it in a script and run the script - exact same.

I am expecting the X-Priority to show the mail as high priority in Outlook. If I run it from command line, I see the email is showing correctly as high priority and I see the file is attached and the body appear as supposed to. However, if I write it a shell script and run the script, the mail come formatted as text and attachment is appended to the body of the email and the email is shown as normal in outlook.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Shell Script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Message Body" | mail -r "sender@mycom.com" -c "ccrecipient@mycom.com" -s "$(echo -e "Message Subject\nX-Priority: 1")" -a "logFile.log" "torecipient@mycom.com"
```

Also tested with
Shell Script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Message Body" | /usr/bin/mail -r "sender@mycom.com" -c "ccrecipient@mycom.com" -s "$(echo -e "Message Subject\nX-Priority: 1")" -a "logFile.log" "torecipient@mycom.com"
```

Command line

`echo "Message Body" | mail -r "sender@mycom.com" -c "ccrecipient@mycom.com" -s "$(echo -e "Message Subject\nX-Priority: 1")" -a "logFile.log" "torecipient@mycom.com"`

### EDIT: More Details/Observation on further R&D:

In Subject, in my actual command, there is a variable assignment like `MyApp : ${HostName} : Restarted\nX-Priority: 1`.
`HostName` is a variable i defined in the script.
If I replace the variable hard-coded value like `MyApp : myserver : Restarted\nX-Priority: 1`, the command line and script behave the exact same.
If I keep the variable in command line, it works as expected (the X-Priority part) but the subject comes as `MyApp :  : Restarted` as expected as the variable is not defined.

I tried to add an undefined variable in script and it still did not work.

Hope this gives more insights into the issue.

---

Note: I originally asked this question in stackoverflow. But I was advised to ask it here instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75585298/mail-not-working-in-script-same-way-it-is-working-from-command-line

--

Comment: Are the shells the same?  You have your script as /bin/sh but what is your command line using?  ksh, bash, and sh will sometimes behave differently for certain utilities/commands in my experience.

Comment: I tested with both sh and bash - my terminal is using bash by default. Getting same output in both.

Comment: If your terminal is normally bash then why write scripts in anything else?  "#! /bin/bash" keeps everything on a level playing field.  Just to rule out a fairly obvious suspect here - just how are you running this "script" of yours?  Interactively, in the terminal, yes?  Not through, say, *cron*?

Comment: @PhillW., sorry I was not clear. I tried with both scripts - with bash and with sh - I just posted the latest script I was working on. Both gave the same output.

Comment: Get the path of the mail command from your shell with "which mail", also check the output of "alias mail". Substitute the explicit value in your shell script, re-test and avise on whether this had any impact.

Comment: Below is the output of the commands.

[root@myserver ~]$ which mail
/usr/bin/mail
[root@myserver ~]$ alias mail
-bash: alias: mail: not found
[root@myserver ~]$

Comment: Updated the script with that and still getting the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

What OS/Distro are you using?

Many distros are commonly using BSD `mailx` as an alias to the `mail` command, but then there might be an alternate or when your script runs, it has a different PATH and therefore uses a different program to the one you expect. (As perhaps your OS has some other ideas for what `mail` for users should do.)

Try from your terminal:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Then the same in your script to see if there's something different about the PATHS

BSD `mailx` will be in somewhere like `/usr/bin/mailx`

It looks like it has different options to whatever `mail` command you are using, though. (See `man mailx` / `man mail`). Are you trying to get:

```
Subject: Message Subject 
  X-Priority: 1
```

Or the subject, then an additional header:

```
Subject: Message Subject
X-Priority: 1
```

`bash` will strip newlines from variables if you try to use them like that to invoke another command.

If it's `mailx`:

- **-a** Specify **additional header fields** on the command line such as "X-Loop: foo@bar" etc.

I'd try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Message Body" | /usr/bin/mailx -a "X-Priority: 1" -s "Message Subject" -r sender@mycom.com -c ccrecipient@mycom.com -- torecipient@mycom.com
```

I don't think there is an (easy) way to get the stock mail/mailx to add attachments, though. It's not a thing it can do.

You could use an alternative like `mutt` or `neomutt`:

```
options:

  --            Special argument forces NeoMutt to stop option parsing and treat
                remaining arguments as addresses even if they start with a dash

  -a <file>     Attach one or more files to a message (must be the last option)
                Add any addresses after the '--' argument

  -c <address>  Specify a carbon copy (Cc) recipient

  -s <subject>  Specify a subject (must be enclosed in quotes if it has spaces)
```

Sounds like it will do more like what you want anyway.

```
echo "Message Body" | mutt -s "Message Subject" \ 
-e "my_hdr X-Priority: 1" \
-e "my_hdr From: sender@mycom.com" \ 
-c ccrecipient@mycom.com \
-a /path/to/logFile.log \
-- torecipient@mycom.com


echo "Message Body" | mutt -s "Message Subject" -e "my_hdr X-Priority: 1" -e "my_hdr From: sender@mycom.com" -c ccrecipient@mycom.com -a /path/to/logFile.log -- torecipient@mycom.com
```